# jQuery HTML5 audio stops, when user exits page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, html5-audio

I am not versed in js or jquery, and I currently have playlists and html5 audio files on my site. Right now, when a user leave the page, if audio was playing it keeps playing. There becomes no way to turn it off. I had it so keyboard controls were on, but if a user went to a web form the audio would turn on and off every time you hit the space key. Anyway, here is my javascript for the playlist. I am stuck after that. I am also using this with Rails 5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var hap_player;
  jQuery(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var settings = {
      instanceName: "artwork5",
      sourcePath: "",
      activePlaylist: "",
      activeItem: 0,
      volume: 0.5,
      autoPlay: false,
      preload: "auto",
      randomPlay: false,
      loopingOn: true,
      mediaEndAction: "next",
      soundCloudAppId: "",
      gDriveAppId: "",
      usePlaylistScroll: true,
      playlistScrollOrientation: "vertical",
      playlistScrollTheme: "dark-2",
      useKeyboardNavigationForPlayback: false,
      facebookAppId: "644413448983338",
      useNumbersInPlaylist: true,
      sortableTracks: false,
      playlistItemContent: "title"
    };

    hap_player = $("#hap-wrapper").hap(settings);

    $('.hap-playlist-toggle').on('click', function() {
      var playerHolder = $('.hap-player-holder'),
        ease = 'easeInOutCubic',
        time = 500,
        openValue = $("#hap-wrapper").width() - 50;

      if (!hap_player.playlistOpened) {
        playerHolder.stop().animate({
          'left': openValue + 'px'
        }, {
          duration: time,
          easing: ease,
          complete: function() {
            playerHolder.addClass('hap-player-holder-opened');
          }
        });
      } else {
        playerHolder.css('left', playerHolder.css('left')).removeClass('hap-player-holder-opened').stop().animate({
          'left': 0 + 'px'
        }, {
          duration: time,
          easing: ease
        });
      }
      hap_player.playlistOpened = !hap_player.playlistOpened;
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand this code, but you should think in events. For example, there is an event called onfocusout in wich you could execute a function that stops the sound when focus is out of something, or onkeyup to detects which key was hit, to execute something you want.

Comment: What is the library you use for your player ? Furthermore, If you can give us a jsfiddle with working code, will help us to help you ;-)

Comment: It's a html5 jquery player I got from codecanyon. The author said to try listening for onunload, onbeforeunload events, but I have no idea about how to implement these things. There are about 7 different js files included in the particular playlist that I have to use. I don't know how I would make a js fiddle under those conditions.